# Is a linear vector space a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

On the first page of the classical book "Ordinary Differential Equations" by Jack Hale (Revised Edition, 1980) there is the following definition:

> An *abstract linear vector space* (or *linear space*) $\mathcal{X}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is a collection of elements $\{x,y,\ldots\}$ such that for each $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$, the sum $x+y$ is defined, $x+y \in \mathcal{X}$, $x+y=y+x$ and there is an element $0 \in \mathcal{X}$ such that $x+0=x$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$. Also, for any number $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, scalar multiplication $ax$ is defined, $ax \in \mathcal{X}$ and $1 \cdot x = x$, $(ab)x=a(bx)=b(ax)$, $(a+b)x=ax+bx$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$.

The terminology *linear* vector space is the same as vector space (i.e., without the adjective *linear*)? I am asking this because a classical axiom of vector spaces is missing here: given an $x \in \mathcal{X}$ there is an element $z \in \mathcal{X}$ such that $x+z=0$, where the element $0$ was defined above.

**Question improvement**: with respect to the definition of *vector space*, more axioms seem to be missing too, namely the associativity under $+$ and the scalar distributivity as $a(x+y) = ax + ay$. This was mentioned by more than one comment/post of contributors.

Why is that?

Comment: It is the same...and I can't understand why you think the existence of neutral element is missing as it is clearly written there!

Comment: It looks like you can prove it from the distribution property you have at the end here

Comment: First prove 0*x =0. Then prove the existence of the additive inverse.

Comment: Additive inverses exist by the very last line of your definition. $0=0x=(1-1)x=x-x

Comment: Also, the reason for this is the philosophy that the less we have to assume about our mathematical system, the stronger the system is.

Comment: Is the object Hale defines associative under $+$?

Comment: @Jake but why does $0x=0$?

Comment: Actually it seems to me that these axioms might not be good enough after all. Specifically, while it's clear how to show that additive inverses exist if we know $0\cdot x=0$ for all vectors $x$, I don't see how to prove that from the axioms given. (More specifically: it's easy to show that $0\cdot x+x=x$, but I don't see how to show $0\cdot x+y=y$ for *arbitrary* $y$ from the axioms given.) Additionally, those axioms don't seem to include associativity for vector addition, which is pretty important. I don't immediately see how to build a counterexample, though, so I might be missing something.

Comment: @Noah Schweber : I am sure the lack of associativity is the root of the difficulties. I *think* that the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with non-dpendent vectors adding to $0$ provides a Hale space that is not a vector space.

Comment: @ancientmathematician What's a Hale space? (Googling is only turning up "Thomas Hale, space detective" which sounds awesome but not entirely relevant.) And that example seems to work - you should post it as an answer. (Although even with associativity I don't see how to solve the problem of additive inverses - am I missing something?)

Comment: Sorry I just meant the sort of object Hale defines in the OP's post.

Comment: Also missing from the usual axioms is $a(x+y)=ax+ay$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh wow, yeah, I missed that. This is *terrible* (unless "abstract linear vector space" means something wildly different from what it should).

Comment: Page 1 (and other pages) of a version of this book [can be seen on Google Books](https://books.google.dk/books?id=LdTZJ4HwCv4C&lpg=PA13&hl=da&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) where the quote can be seen inline in the text (no box) very early in section 0.1.

Comment: While you are correct that the definition is incorrect, it is wise to note that this first page glitch is used nowhere in the whole book since all that is linear happens then always on $\mathbb R^n$. In addition, the expression "linear vector space" was quite common in the old days among some people: use google and you will find dozens of books using the expression.

Comment: @JohnB Do you know what the motivation for this was? I can understand "linear space" or "abstract vector space" to distance oneself from connotations of "vector" from physics e.g. co-/contra-variance. But "linear vector space", let alone "abstract linear vector space", seems misleadingly redundant, like saying "commutative field".

Comment: @DerekElkins Sorry, I can't add anything on the motivation. I agree that it is a peculiar choice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.  Consider $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1\}$, with addition defined by $x+y=\max(x,y)$ and scalar multiplication defined by $ax=x$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathcal{X}$.  This satisfies all of Hale's axioms, but $1$ has no additive inverse.

Here's a slightly less trivial example.  Consider the set $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{z\}$, with addition and scalar multiplication defined as usual for elements of $\mathbb{R}$, $x+z=z+x=x$ for all $x\in\mathcal{X}$, and $az=z$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  This satisfies the given axioms, with $z$ as the zero element.  However, no element other than $z$ has an additive inverse.

(In fact, any example without additive inverses contains a copy of the first counterexample.  If $\mathcal{X}$ satisfies Hale's axioms and $x\in\mathcal{X}$ has no additive inverse, then $\{0,0\cdot x\}\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ will be closed under addition and scalar multiplication and isomorphic to the first example, sending $0\cdot x$ to $1$.  We must have $0\cdot x\neq 0$ since $x+(-1)\cdot x=0\cdot x$ so $x$ would have an additive inverse if $0\cdot x=0$.)

---

Note, though, that additive inverses aren't the only axiom that is missing.  Associativity of $+$ and $a(x+y)=ax+ay$ are missing too!  Here's an example that has additive inverses but which fails associativity.  Let $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}\setminus\{(0,1)\}$.  We define addition by $(x,i)+(y,j)=(x+y,\max(i,j))$ and scalar multiplication by $a(x,i)=(ax,i)$, except that if either operation gives an output of $(0,1)$, we change it to $(0,0)$ instead (so for instance, $0(x,1)=(0,0)$ for any $x$).  This satisfies Hale's axioms, and has additive inverses ($(-x,i)$ is the inverse of $(x,i)$).  However, it fails associativity, since $$((x,0)+(-x,0))+(x,1)=(0,0)+(x,1)=(x,1)$$ whereas $$(x,0)+((-x,0)+(x,1))=(x,0)+(0,0)=(x,0)$$ for any $x\neq 0$.

---

The author almost certainly does not intend to give a different definition from the usual one, though--this is just an error in the book.  It is definitely not standard to use the term "linear vector space" to refer to this weaker definition.

Comment: Nice minimal counterexample and inclusion proof. Too bad I can't give you an second +1.

Answer (score 18):

The definition is indeed missing something for a vector space, but I suspect that is not intentional. “Linear space” is a common synonym of “vector space”, probably because it is linear functions that respect the structure of a vector space.

To see that the conditions are not sufficient, consider $\mathcal X = \mathbb R\times \mathbb N$ with the addition $(a,m)+(b,n) = (a+b,\max\{m,n\})$ and the multiplication $a(b,n)=(ab,n)$.

Comment: That's a nice example.  It contains my example as a substructure (namely, $\{(0,0)\}\cup\{n\}\times\mathbb{R}$ for any $n>0$).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks. Actually, I suspect your example is the minimal one.

Comment: I was just thinking about that question, and it's not! I'm about to add that to my answer. :)